# CSS Margin with RTL elements

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV that is declared with ***style="direction:ltr***" in-order to display right to left items.

My issue that if I declare a div with a right margin (***margin-right***), this margin does not automatically switch to the left side when the div is RTL.

This forces me to style every div that I want to be RTL with ***margin-left***.

Can I use some CSS paramter that would always put the margin at the end of the DIV and will automatically switch when using RTL? (Horizontally)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.container{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}

.text{
    margin-right:30px;
}

</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="text">On this DIV the margin between the text and the icon is correct.</div>
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-inbox" style="margin-right:3px; font-size:24px"></i><div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="direction:rtl">
    <div class="text">On this RTL DIV the margin between the text and the icon is missing because the margin parameter is <b>margin-right</div>
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-inbox" style="margin-right:3px; font-size:24px"></i><div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Are you complaining because using margin-right actually puts the margin on the right?

Comment: I am trying to insert a margin between the text and icon. With left-to-right pages, the end of the text div is on the right. So put I margin-right. But with RTL div, the the end of the div is now on the left. I am looking for a CSS parameter that will know to automatically switch to the other side once the div is RTL.

Comment: AFAIK...there isn't an "automatic" parameter. If you're applying the `direction` I'd use a class and adjust the CSS accordingly...

Comment: how about this: https://jsfiddle.net/a79twmwy/12/

Comment: There's now CSS logical properties for just such a thing https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties/Margins_borders_padding

Answer (score 17):

Use css property "...-inline-start" instead, that will align it to either the left or the right depending on the browser direction. You can test that easily by adding dir="rtl" to the html element.

```
.text {
    margin-inline-start: 10px;
}
```

PS.: inline is for left/right, use block for top/bottom, e.g. margin-block-start to add margin to the top, padding-inline-start to add padding to the left in ltr languages and rigth in rtl languages

Comment: You deserve the bests. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can differentiate the elements in even or odd, to give them a margin to each as appropriate. Or the container to give another class makes them different, such as `container left-to-right` and `container right-to-left`.

```
.container:nth-child(odd) .text {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.container:nth-child(even) .text {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Or this:

```
.container.left-to-right .text {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.container.right-to-left .text {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/a9r3csqy/5/)

Answer (score 1):

**Pure CSS** approach

instead of using `left` or `right` use `*-inline-start` and `*-inline-end`

```css
.ltr { /*default not required*/ }
.rtl { direction: rtl; }
.mainDiv { border: 1px solid #DD9900; padding: 10px; }
.childDiv {
  margin-inline-end: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #99DD00;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="childDiv ltr"> Hello World </div> 
  <div class="childDiv rtl"> مرحبا بالعالم </div>
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline-start